# How do I implement this array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
Array ( [254] => OnJob [251] => Verified [250] => Verified [249] => OnJob [248] => OnJob [247] => OnJob [244] => OnJob )
```

I have this array , now I want to get each value for the respective array key . How to do this in javascript ?

Comment: So are each of those numbers indexes/keys in the overall array? And you mention wanting to do this in JavaScript... is this in something else to start with eg PHP?

Comment: Have you done some research on how to work with arrays in Javascript? Maybe should you look there to get to know more about Arrays in JS : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Comment: whattt ??? `arrayname[indexvalue]`

Comment: I have to do this in javascript  .. yes I did  .. arrayname[indexvalue] doesn't work for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an object

```
my_object={254: 'OnJob',251: 'Verified', 250: 'Verified',249: 'OnJob'};
my_object[251]; //return "Verified"
```